# Best way to extend pure-css's grid to have gutters

Tags: css, yui-pure-css

I'm coming to Pure CSS (the Yahoo! framework) from a SUITCSS background and am looking for a neat way to add gutters to multi-column grids.

I've seen mention of the l-box technique, but can't find a decent example of it.

Here's what I'm currently trying, by adding the pure-g--gutter class:

```
.pure-g .pure-g--gutter {
  margin: 0 -0.5rem;
}

.pure-g .pure-g--gutter > div {
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}
```

Unfortunately, while this does appear to set the margins and padding as expected, it also causes the grid to reflow the second column (of two) onto the next line.

PureCSSers: What do you use to achieve guttered grid columns?

Comment: Why use padding? Just add margin to inner elements. `.pure-g .pure-g--gutter > div > * {margin: 0 0.5rem}`

Comment: Will try that later and get back to you - cheers.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer. If it doesn't work, I'll delete it. Good luck!

Comment: Check out _Step 2_ [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/crash-course-yui-grids-css--net-14980). Tell me if that contains what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusHofmann - that looks like it should work, too, but I wanted a solution that needed no supporting markup (`first`, `last` etc). I appreciate the link, though

Comment: @stevejalim Ok, good to see that you got it working now :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's unnecessary to use `padding` when you can add margin to the children.

```
.pure-g .pure-g--gutter > div > * {
    margin: 0 0.5rem;
}
```

Comment: Yup. Does the trick. I'd assumed the padding was to counteract the margin, but when you made me step back and think about it, it made perfect sense. Cheers - was too close to see it. 500 karma very well spent!

Comment: This is so slow though!

Comment: @JonasG.Drange If you're worried about every possible performance issue in CSS, don't use a framework.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make the box-sizing of each grid border-box and add padding so that the inner content leaves space between the borders:

```css
.pure-g > div[class*="pure-u-"] {
  padding: 1em;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Each grid column has padding inside so that child div in the colum will have space. Add a background to the child div so the space shows.

Check it out in action on my codepen: http://codepen.io/ecupaio/pen/bpWJMr

Comment: This worked like a charm!  Quick and easy to add class in my parent wrapper <div class="pure-g grid-padding"> _CSS_ .grid-padding.pure-g > div[class*="pure-u-"] {...}  see the codepen solution